# a matrix metric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-computation

Let $U_1,...,U_n$ and $V_1,...,V_n$ be two sets of $n$ unitary matrices of the same size.
We'll denote $E(U_i,V_i)= \max_v \, |(U_i -V_i)v|$ (max over all the [quantum states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state)), $U=\prod_i U_i$ and $V=\prod_i V_i$.

I'd like to show that $E(U,V) \leq \sum_i E(U_i,V_i) $.

At first I thought proving this by induction on $n$, but then I got stuck even in the simple case of $n=2$.

I also tried expanding the expression: $$E(U,V)=\max_v |(\prod U_i - \prod V_i)v | $$

But I got stuck on here too. Maybe there's an easier way I'm missing out?

Edit: $U_i, V_i$ are [unitary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix)

Comment: you need to put constraints on $v$. otherwise $E$ isn't well defined.

Comment: by quantum state in this context you mean a complex vector with norm = 1?

Comment: @user251257 Yes

Comment: are you sure that the claim is valid? the metric looks like the one induced by operator norm, with is submultiplcative. but I never saw something similar.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $U_i, V_i$ are unitary matrices, orelse as you said the claim wont hold.

Comment: It was very unfortunate to use the notation $U_i$ for both a set of matrices and for a single matrix. I suggest that you use $\mathcal U _i$  and $\mathcal V _i$ for sets (produce them with `\mathcal`). (I didn't edit your question, though, fearing that I might have misunderstood something.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $||.||$ be the matrix norm induced by the $l_2$ norm over $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then (if I correctly understand the question) $E(U,V)=||U-V||$. Note that, if $U$ is unitary, then $||U||=1$ and that the set of unitary matrices is a group.

Case $n=2$. $||U_1U_2-V_1V_2||=||(U_1-V_1)U_2+V_1(U_2-V_2)||\leq ||U_1-V_1||||U_2||+||V_1||||U_2-V_2||$ and we are done.

Case $n=3$. According to the previous calculation, $||U_1U_2U_3-V_1V_2V_3||\leq ||U_1U_2-V_1V_2||+||U_3-V_3||\leq ||U_1-V_1||+||U_2-V_2||+||U_3-V_3||$.

Case $n>3$. And so on...